# Identify all xml files with specific format

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to find xmls which are not having valid data and not process them. For example , below is a correct xml with all the data available which needs to be processes

(Loop Xpath used to read the data from xml files- Invoicing/Invoice/Serials/SerialNumber):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Invoicing>
    <Invoice>
        <VendorName>Contec</VendorName>
        <InvoicePeriod>May</InvoicePeriod>
        <InvoiceDt>2019-05-11</InvoiceDt>
        <InvoiceNo>20190511</InvoiceNo>
        <Serials>
            <SerialNumber>
                <TestLoc>HNMA01</TestLoc>
                <EISSerial>PKQPLPXJC</EISSerial>
                <ComcastModel>PX022ANC</ComcastModel>
                <RMANo />
                <ReceiptDt>05/09/2019</ReceiptDt>
                <RepairDt>05/11/2019</RepairDt>
                <Parts>
                    <Part>
                        <PartType>Cosmetic</PartType>
                        <PartId>SERVICEBUFFING</PartId>
                        <PartDescr>BUFF SERVC</PartDescr>
                        <ActionCd>RA003</ActionCd>
                        <FSC>FS005</FSC>
                    </Part>
                </Parts>
            </SerialNumber>
        </Serials>
    </Invoice>
</Invoicing>
```

I also get XML which are in below format,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoicing>
    <Invoice>
        <VendorName>Contec</VendorName>
        <InvoicePeriod>May</InvoicePeriod>
        <InvoiceDt>2017-05-01</InvoiceDt>
        <InvoiceNo>20170501</InvoiceNo>
        <Serials></Serials>
    </Invoice>
</Invoicing>
```

The above xml , even though being valid is not correct..I want to identify the xmls which are in the second format without the complete data and move them into a error folder.

Thanks,
Kavin

Comment: There's no `SerialNumber` in that sample input file. Please clarify your requirements and update the example if necessary.

Comment: @EdMorton Thats the thing, am trying to identify such files and eliminate them from daily processing.

Comment: So you told us a desired format but then showed us a file that ISN'T in that format as your [mcve]??? OK, I updated my answer, see the extra script at the end.

Comment: @EdMorton i have updated my question , i hope its more clear now. Really sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Include an example demonstrating why `grep -l '<SerialNumber>' *` isn't all you need.

Comment: grep -l '<SerialNumber>' *.xml ,does the reverse of what am looking for... just returns the xml file in which the <SerialNumber> has data. But that not what am looking for, am looking for xml files without <SerialNumber> data. Thanks

Comment: OK then `grep -L '<SerialNumber>' *.xml`. I'm just trying to get you to tell me if you really need an XML parser for this (e.g. if `<SerialNumber>` shows up in other contexts than the desired one) or not.

Comment: grep -L '<SerialNumber>' *.xml , works great!  Well, with my limited unix knowledge i thought only a xml parser could achieve this. But just curious, is there a xml parser way to get this done ? like using xmllint ? Asking this just to learn, thanks for all the help sir!

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this question is as follows :

I was able to achieve what i wanted with the solution provided by @EdMorton.

```
grep -L '<SerialNumber>' *.xml
```

But i wanted to get this done using a xml parser.

```
count=$(xmllint --xpath "count(//SerialNumber)" "$xml")
```

When the count is zero i have implemented my logic.

Thanks for all the help.